# Attribute a value based on different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
db1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["value", "type",'type2'], data=[[1, "A","ca"],[2, "B","cb"],[3, "C","cc"],[4, "D",'dd'],[5, "E",'ee'],["Nan","F",'ff']]
)
print(db1)

db2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["value", "type"], data=[["Nan", "A"],["Nan", "F"]]
)

db1

    value   type    type2
0   1       A       ca
1   2       B       cb
2   3       C       cc
3   4       D       dd
4   5       E       ee
5   Nan     F       ff

db2

    value   type
0   Nan     A
1   Nan     F
```

I want to have in a new column of db2 the value of "type2" if (db1['type'] == db2['type']) & (db1['value'] == db2['value'])

like that:

```
db2

value   type    new
Nan     A   
Nan     F       ff
```

I try something but it doesn't work

```
db2["new"] =np.nan

db2["new"]= np.where((db1['type'] == db2['type']) & (db1['value'] == db2['value']), db2['type2'], '')
```

Thanks!

Comment: `db2.merge(db1, how='left').rename(columns={'type2':'new'})`?

Comment: Yes, it works, but if I want to change the condition for inequation or other , it's not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (kind of ugly but work :)

```
import pandas as pd 
db1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["value", "type",'type2'], data=[[1, "A","ca"],[2, "B","cb"],[3, "C","cc"],[4, "D",'dd'],[5, "E",'ee'],["Nan","F",'ff']]
)
print(db1)

db2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["value", "type"], data=[["Nan", "A"],["Nan", "F"]]
)
for index,row in db2.iterrows():
    type_=db2.loc[index,'type']
    value_=db2.loc[index,'value']
    
    df_tempo=db1.loc[(db1['type']==type_)&(db1['value']==value_),:]
    if df_tempo.shape[0]==1 : 
        db2.loc[index,'new']=df_tempo['type2'].values[0]
    else : 
        db2.loc[index,'new']='no_val'
```

Output :

```
db2
    value   type    new
0   nan     A      no_val
1   nan     F      ff
2   3       F      no_val
```

If you only to keep the match between both of them :

```
db2=db2.loc[db2['new']!='no_val',:]
db2
    value   type    new
1   Nan     F       ff
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can just do a merge and that should give you the results you are expecting

```
pd.merge(db1, db2, on = ['value', 'type'])
```

And if you wanted to keep data from the db2 like you have in your example you could add a how = 'right' to ensure that no matter what all db2 rows are present

```
pd.merge(db1, db2, on = ['value', 'type'], how = 'right')
```